# Question on "Top Network Post" section :

Tags: support, profile-page, user-profile

I am new to MSE. Can anyone tell me what is the "Top Network Post" section on the south-left corner my profile? Which items can I add there and how?

Comment: You can't add posts there yourself, it's automatic. As far as I know, it's a list of your highest-voted posts made on other sites of the network than the site on which you view the profile (the top posts from the current site have their own division).

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer .